# Stop curly braces navigation from leaving marks

Tags: mark, navigation

When using curly braces navigation, `{`, `}`, to move between paragraph, overwrites the "last jump" mark (the one accessible via `''`). I would find it more useful if it left this mark untouched. Is there any way to configure vim like this?

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question over at [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356354/vim-stop-curly-braces-navigation-from-leaving-marks) where DJMcMayhem prvoided an excellent answer:

> You can use the `keepjumps` command. From `:h :keepjumps`:
>
> ```
>                         *:keepj* *:keepjumps* :keepj[umps] {command}
>         Moving around in {command} does not change the |''|,
>         |'.| and |'^| marks, the |jumplist| or the
>         |changelist|.
>         Useful when making a change or inserting text
>         automatically and the user doesn't want to go to this
>         position.
> ```
>
> So in your case, you'd want
>
> ```
> nnoremap } :keepjumps normal! }<cr>
> nnoremap { :keepjumps normal! {<cr>
> ```
>
> Or, if you want it to work for visual mode too (which your
>   probably do):
>
> ```
> xnoremap } :<C-u>keepjumps normal! gv}<cr>
> xnoremap { :<C-u>keepjumps normal! gv{<cr>
> ```